# Issues with 'waitForUser' macro from ImageJ plugin

Tags: plugins, macros, imagej

I am developing an ImageJ plugin to do some image analysis. I have a series of macros which I'd like to run from within the plugin.

Using

```
new Macro_Runner().runMacroFromJar("macro.txt", "macro title");
```

I am able to call each of the macros from within the plugin.

Although this seems to work, the macros stall whenever they get to a

```
waitForUser();
```

line. The ImageJ windows stop updating, commands are not accepted and it is necessary to Alt-Ctrl-Del to quit the program.

Does anyone have any ideas what causes this to happen?

Best wishes

Ben

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the issue. It is related to using WaitForUser inside a Swing gui.

Solved by spawning a new thread to run the macro in. See here:

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.imagej/15921/focus=15924